# Path to assets is rendered wrong in Rails 5 app on mobile, works in desktop browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

Serving a Rails 5 app in production gives wrong asset paths on mobile safari, but the right paths on a desktop browser. This causes e.g. images and web-fonts not to load on mobile safari. In development mode everyhting works fine, so the precompiling of the assets in production must have something to do with it.

E.g.

```
<%= image_tag "dl.jpg", class:"circle" %>
```

loads the image fine on desktop browser in production but does not load on mobile safari. Inspection using safari dev tools shows the path for this image to be

```
<img class="circle" src="/assets/dl-1f02b49f15b7f44be3f8a5c5fd8e66aece7cc2a5efc5979821fce8c891904858.jpg">
```

in a desktop browser, and that works fine, but it is

```
<img class="circle" src="dl-1f02b49f15b7f44be3f8a5c5fd8e66aece7cc2a5efc5979821fce8c891904858.jpg">
```

on mobile safari. So naturally the browser does not load that image.

From all other desktop browsers (chrome, ff, ie) it all work fine.

I'm using Rails 5.1.4, and as command to precompile the assets I use:

bundle exec rake assets:precompile db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production

I don't know what causes the asset path to be rendered different based on device.

Things I tried but did not help: Clearing the mobile safari browser cache, clearing the precompiled assets using assets:clobber, clearing the webserver cache, restarting the application and the web server.

Other info: production environment is using Phussion Passenger 5.1.8/nginx 1.12.1

To reproduce: visit http:/gdemo.nl on mobile safari (iphone) and on a desktop browser. The image for the avatar is not load on mobile safari so the text 'DL' is displayed instead. On a desktop browser the image for the avatar is displayed fine.

Comment: You may try disabling turbolinks to see if that solves your problem.  Just a guess, but it may work.

Comment: Thx!, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Disabling turbo links did not change the behaviour. But putting the CSS link to the web fonts in the HTML code and not in the SCSS (so not using @import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"; in application.scss but simply putting <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"> in application.html.erb did work. I still don't know what caused this but it works correctly now.

Comment: Good.  Glad it is working.